# Как правильно реализовать компонентную архитектуру проекта?

Tags: node.js

Наткнулся на данную статью на гитхабе: https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices#1-project-structure-practices

Показался очень адекватным компонентный подход, но не нахожу ни одного проекта реализованного с помощью этого подхода.

Скажите, насколько данный подход вообще актуален?

Буду очень рад если найдутся хорошие примеры реализации такого подхода.

На данный момент не совсем понимаю каким образом компоненты связываются друг с другом и куда выносить такие штуки как конфиги условного mongo, redis, passport и все в этом духе.

Comment: Посмотрите react или vue компонентов сплош и рядом

Answer (score 0):

Подход актуальный на сегодняшний день. Посмотрите примеры фронтенд фреймворков React, Vue, Angular на github их там тысячи.
Вам нужно понять как компоненты взаимодействуют. А для простоты представьте что компонент это обычный класс и использование его это как создание экземпляра класса (объект). Mongo, Redis  это серверная часть проекта и общение происходит на уровне request response фронтендом.  Я только попытался объяснить более или менее в двух словах. На самом деле практик очень много и я не претендую на истину в последней инстанции.